# GRUB 2 Error : No such disk

Tags: boot, grub2, mbr

I have gone through many pains to boot through my windows 7 partition.

I had windows 7, then one fine day I installed Ubuntu and again formatted the partition where Ubuntu was installed only to find the my Windows does not boot(Probably corrupted MBR).

I again installed Ubuntu later but the Grub could not detect windows.

So I manually added windows by editing the file 40_custom. But when I select the win7 entry in the grub, it displays the error : no such disk. What do I do??

Additional Info : 
Ubuntu version : 11.10 x64||
Win 7 Home premium, 64 bit||
While in the process of debugging I once also came across the error : Sector 32 being in use by FlexNet.||
Strongly in need of booting my Win 7 without any formats or fresh OS installations.

Thankful for any Diagnostics and Solutions to my problem.

Comment: Edit your question to show the output of `sudo fdisk -lu`, and what partition you pointed grub to in 40_custom.

Comment: /dev/sda1     63        208844      104391   de  Dell Utility
||||||
/dev/sda2     208896    30928895    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
||||||
/dev/sda3   * 30928896   432075772   200573438+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
||||||
/dev/sda4     432076798   976771071   272347137    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
||||||
/dev/sda5     432076800   439936174     3929687+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
||||||
/dev/sda6     510949376   976771071   232910848    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: As I said, please edit your question and add that info so it is readable instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s Recommended repair, and indicate the URL that will appear. This will help us understand your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed grub errors using [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `update-grub`?

I hope you have installed both times grub to the same place. Mbr or partition, because there could be two grubs and only one is active (I do).

Start a terminal with Strng+Alt+T and type `sudo update-grub`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then your admin password is needed, it will not be shown, don´t worry, <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and with luck the grub finds Windows, two ones the loader and recovery.

Comment: no it did not work..

Comment: Then use a recovery-CD of win7. It will repair the MBR and install a win boot-loader, which finds ubuntu.  If this is not working, perhaps the ntfs partition of win is damaged.

Comment: The windows boot loader does not find Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry, of course. I meant boot-manager, in win this happens automatically

Comment: the problem is even the windows cd can't find my windows partiton, but let me tell you the files are intact and i can access them using a Ubuntu live CD. I also tried fixboot fixmbr but even they could not give any results... it's also strange that when i try to install a fresh windows 7 install there pops up a new error : please place a DVD/CD which contains the drivers, looks like the win 7 cd needs some drivers of my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this "super grub disk" worked on my system also. You must look at the start careful to get the right entry, x32 or x64 machine!, it´s not easy to read because of the colour.
The problem is grub itself on competition with win. I have now 12 entries, 4kubuntu,6ubuntu,2win+2memory, boring. With lilo or win boot-manager there was nothing like this.